# JavaFX Combo Box Seeing Instances of warehouses

Tags: java, javafx

I have a controller that has a combobox defined as so:

```
private ComboBox warehouseComboBox;
```

and a method that populates that combobox in that controller

```
@FXML
void createWarehouseInstance (ActionEvent event){

    ArrayList<BikePart> inventory = new ArrayList<>(); //empty inventory
    String whName = warehouseNameField.getText();
    warehouse wh = new warehouse(whName, inventory); //create new instance

    warehouseComboBox.getItems().add(wh);

    warehouseArrayList.add(wh); //add instance to arrayList

    warehouseNameField.clear(); //clear text box


}
```

What I'm trying to do is get the state of that combobox and that determines which instance of a class I would be manipulating.

My attempt is so with this method. Where I show a list of Bicycle parts depending on the instance selected with the combo box.

```
@FXML
void showParts(){

    bikePartList.clear();

    bikePartList.appendText("Name\tNumber\tListPrice\tSalePrice\tQuantity\tOnSale?\n");

    Object selection = warehouseComboBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();

    if (warehouseArrayList.contains(selection)){

        bikePartList.appendText(warehouse.printAll()); //what do I do here?

    }

}
```

For context, Warehouses hold BikeParts, and I'm figuring out that if I want to dynamically create warehouses, I can't make this static

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you're trying to do:

First declare your `ComboBox` with the proper type:

```
private ComboBox<Warehouse> warehouseComboBox;
```

and then you can do

```
@FXML
void showParts(){

    bikePartList.clear();

    bikePartList.appendText("Name\tNumber\tListPrice\tSalePrice\tQuantity\tOnSale?\n");

    Warehouse selectedWarehouse = warehouseComboBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();

    // I think this is what you're trying to do:
    bikePartList.appendText(selectedWarehouse.printAll()); //what do I do here?


}
```

Note that I changed your class name to conform to [standard naming conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java).

Comment: That's it, this was stumping me for a little while, thank you!

Comment: @xsccmx There is basically never a reason to use raw types in JavaFX. You should be seeing warnings from your IDE on this (unless you have disabled them).

Comment: Then should I be calling Warehouse.printAll ?

Comment: @xsccmx Given that I don't know what that method does, I can't answer that question. My point is that if you declare the combo box correctly, as in the answer, then the return type of `getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem()` is `Warehouse`, not `Object`, which gives you what you need.